# <shiro:hasRole ..> Tag does not work cause NoSuchMethodException Exception

Tags: jsf-2, tags, shiro

can you please provide me a solution for my problem,

I have an integration with Apache Shiro and once i use shiro:hasRole tag or other tags an exception has been thrown says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.shiro.web.tags.HasRoleTag.<init>(javax.faces.view.facelets.TagConfig)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$HandlerFactory.createHandler(AbstractTagLibrary.java:187)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary.createTagHandler(AbstractTagLibrary.java:678)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.CompositeTagLibrary.createTagHandler(CompositeTagLibrary.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TagUnit.createFaceletHandler(TagUnit.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextUnit.createFaceletHandler(TextUnit.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationUnit.getNextFaceletHandler(CompilationUnit.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TagUnit.getNextHandler(TagUnit.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$ComponentConfigWrapper.getNextHandler(AbstractTagLibrary.java:230)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.TagHandler.<init>(TagHandler.java:116)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.<init>(MetaTagHandler.java:105)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.<init>(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:69)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentHandler.<init>(ComponentHandler.java:128)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.html.HtmlComponentHandler.<init>(HtmlComponentHandler.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor19.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$UserComponentHandlerFactory.createHandler(AbstractTagLibrary.java:306)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary.createTagHandler(AbstractTagLibrary.java:678)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.CompositeTagLibrary.createTagHandler(CompositeTagLibrary.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TagUnit.createFaceletHandler(TagUnit.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextUnit.createFaceletHandler(TextUnit.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationUnit.getNextFaceletHandler(CompilationUnit.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TagUnit.getNextHandler(TagUnit.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$ComponentConfigWrapper.getNextHandler(AbstractTagLibrary.java:230)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.TagHandler.<init>(TagHandler.java:116)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.<init>(MetaTagHandler.java:105)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.<init>(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:69)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.ComponentHandler.<init>(ComponentHandler.java:128)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.html.HtmlComponentHandler.<init>(HtmlComponentHandler.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor19.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$UserComponentHandlerFactory.createHandler(AbstractTagLibrary.java:306)
```

Notice that i have a correct shiro configuration whereby the shiro security is applied and the resources are protected where the user must be authenticated and authorized to access the application resources.

But once i try to involve shiro security tags the exception is seen.

I open the shiro java tags such as HasRoleTag and really there is no constructor takes an instance of `javax.faces.view.facelets.TagConfig`
as parameter !

Can you please help me to solve the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.2, Shiro does not ship with JSF support.  The tag that you are looking at is a JSP tag.  Deluan Quintão has written a set of JSF facelet tags for shiro.  You can read his post on using them here: http://techbeats.deluan.com/apache-shiro-tags-for-jsffacelets

Note that his work will be officially incorporated into Shiro as of 1.3. (indeed, it is already in the trunk)

Comment: I read his post but he talked about JSF 1.x and i'm working under JSF 2.x. Also i tried it with another type of exception related to the facelets handler

Comment: I am using the library in the link with JSF2, and specifically I use the HasRole tag, I think you need to provide more details about what you do that produces that error if you want more help